# Redis: Is there a way to add to sorted set only if set is exists?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I am wondering if there is a way to check if a redis sorted set is exists already. if sorted set is exists then add element to it, other way nothing will happen.

because of doing this with `pipeline` so it tacks a lot cost to check if the sorted set is exist, every time out of the redis.

Comment: Hi, As you are doing this with pipeline, I suggest to group this by the key and do a check once for each key, so that you dont have to check for all additions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Malinga. I am doing like this: check existence for every keys with pipeline first, then map the result to the keys, finally `zadd` with pipeline according to the result.

Comment: Ok can i know average number of fields in one sorted set and number of sorted sets

Comment: There are hundreds of elements in each sorted set and hundred thousands of sorted sets. @Malinga

Comment: this mean when you get 100 zadds you might need to do the existence check only few times as they might related to only few sorted sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Lua scripts in a pipeline - the following one will add all arguments to the provided key, providing that the key exists:

```
local exists = redis.call('EXISTS', KEYS[1])
if exists == 1 then
  redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))
end
```

Note: no error checking here (i.e. type of key is a zset, arguments are valid...) to save on CPU cycles, and simplify the example. Also no return code - add it if you need it.

Comment: This code will always run the `ZADD` command (`0` and `1` both evaluate to `true` in Lua when cast to boolean). The right way to do it is `if redis.call('EXISTS', KEYS[1]) == 1 then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` command (returns 1 if key is present else 0) to check if the sorted set is present or not and if the zset exists, then in the callback of exists command you can call the `zadd` to add into the zset.

Also `exists` is a O(1) operation. You can read about it from http://redis.io/commands/exists

**sample code**

```
var r = redis.createClient(6379,"127.0.0.1");
r.exists(zsetKey, function(err, isExists){ 
  if(isExists){ // isExists = 1 if zsetKey exists
    r.zadd(zetKey, score, member, function(insertErr, insertReply){
      // add to zset
    })
  }else{
    //key not present
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But, because of doing with `pipeline`, I can't check existence every time before `zadd`.

Comment: This code is slow because it requires two round-trips to and from the server. But what's worse is that it is not race condition safe: another client could delete the sorted set any time between the `exists()` and the `zadd()` calls. This is a particular nasty type of race condition because it's unlikely to occur until your code is under high load.